# asp.net MVC large byte size files returns a 400 Bad Request when trying to upload image

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm trying to pass an image in a base64 format, however, the client returns a 400 Bad Request when the byte size exceeds somewhere around 280000-290000. Is there any way to "force" the upload despite this?

Here is the relevant code:

View:

```
                <div class="span4 target">
                    <label asp-for="T_Image1" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input id="Image1" asp-for="T_Image1" type="hidden" class="target"/>
                    <span asp-validation-for="T_Image1" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Javascript:

```
    (function ($) {
        var defaults;
        $.event.fix = (function (originalFix) {
            return function (event) {
                event = originalFix.apply(this, arguments);
                if (event.type.indexOf("paste") === 0) {
                    event.clipboardData = event.originalEvent.clipboardData;
                }
                return event;
            };
        })($.event.fix);
        defaults = {
            callback: $.noop,
            matchType: /image.*/
        };
        return ($.fn.pasteImageReader = function (options) {
            if (typeof options === "function") {
                options = {
                    callback: options
                };
            }
            options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this, element;
                element = this;
                $this = $(this);
                return $this.bind("paste", function (event) {
                    var clipboardData, found;
                    found = false;
                    clipboardData = event.clipboardData;
                    return Array.prototype.forEach.call(clipboardData.types, function (type, i) {
                        var file, reader;
                        if (found) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (
                            type.match(options.matchType) ||
                            clipboardData.items[i].type.match(options.matchType)
                        ) {
                            file = clipboardData.items[i].getAsFile();
                            reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onload = function (evt) {
                                return options.callback.call(element, {
                                    dataURL: evt.target.result,
                                    event: evt,
                                    file: file,
                                    name: file.name
                                });
                            };
                            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                            return (found = true);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);

    var dataURL, filename;
    $("html").pasteImageReader(function (results) {
        filename = results.filename, dataURL = results.dataURL;
        $data.text(dataURL);
        $size.val(results.file.size);
        $type.val(results.file.type);
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = dataURL;
        var w = img.width;
        var h = img.height;
        $width.val(w);
        $height.val(h);
        var target = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        var element = target.item(0);

//sets value of hidden field to base64 for the controller
        element.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.value = dataURL; 

        element.files = results.file;
        return $(".active")
            .css({
                backgroundImage: "url(" + dataURL + ")"
            });
    });
```

Please note, I'm not very good at Javascript, I'm not quite sure what I need and what I do not. Please forgive.

Answer (score 0):

this is how to change file size limit

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

### edit

change xxx to desired number

### edit 2

place it in correct order in web config basically find configuration tag in web config the in it find system.web if it existed and add the httpruntime line otherwise add entire systen.web tag with httpruntime in it

Comment: place it in correct order in web config  bascially find configuration tag in web config the in it find system.web if it existed and add the httpruntime line otherwise add entire systen.web tag with httpruntime in it

Comment: @MariusG96 is your problem resolved if yes please mark answer